# What is the equivalent of jupyter's Restart Kernel in Zeppelin/Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm just starting my journey on learning Apache Spark and I'm using Zeppelin to play with it interactively.  So far so good, but once in a while I want to start clean and want to restart the kernel.  I coulnd't find such function in Zeppelin.... does that even exist?

Answer (score 5):

- Go to the interpreter list:

  ```
  http://host:port/#/interpreter
  ```
- Find interpreter of interest.
- Click on restart button.